# How to alter ie Browser Mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I found a lot of links that said adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

or an older version of DOCTYPE forces the browser into compatibility mode. But after repeated attempts with many combinations, seems to me that all it does is alter the **Document Mode** and NOT the **Browser Mode**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet if you just remove your DOCTYPE tag completely or make it invalid that IE will be forced into compatibility view.  Broken markup of some sorts will force this mode.  However, this will surely have other negative consequences for non-IE browsers.

Comment: Seems like putting some bad HTML in there is the only way to force it into compatibility mode :(

Comment: Thought so.  What is your ultimate goal?  Is this intended to be permanent?  It is possible for you to do this at the bottom of your page where other browsers won't be affected.

Comment: The app is under consideration for migration into a newer technology, I just need to find a way to get it to work until then.

Comment: So will this work for you?  Otherwise, I'd really suggest figuring out why you have to rely on compatibility view and fix those issues.

Comment: This app was built about 15 years ago, that why :)

Answer (score 0):

You would like to force IE into compatibility mode?
Also, I don't believe IE will display compatibility mode in the console window.
Are you sure you don't mean quirks mode?

The browser mode function (as I understand it) in IE isn't exactly compatibility mode.
I'm just going to copy/paste from [the official documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx) below.

Browser Mode

Description

IE9

IE9 reports a UA string, version vector, and document mode to match the default browser behavior, which is the most standards-compliant mode in IE9. Use this mode to test how IE9 users experience your site.

IE9 Compatibility View

IE9 reports a UA string, version vector, and document mode, as if it is IE7; however, the UA string also includes the Trident/5.0 token indicating that the browser is really IE9. Use this mode to test how IE9 users experience your site if they click on the Compatibility View button.

IE8

IE9 reports a UA string, version vector, and document mode as if it is IE8. Use this mode to test how IE8 users experience your site.

IE7

IE9 reports a UA string, version vector, and document mode as if it is IE7. Use this mode to test how IE7 users experience your site.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to force this to change no matter what, is to set it on the virtual directory level through IIS in the 'HTTP Headers' section of the properties menu. Changing it here will force the browser into whatever mode you set it to, 100% of the time.

[image]

Changing the setting here overrides whatever browser mode is specified at the web page level.

Comment: That changes the document mode, not the browser mode.

Comment: I already tried that, the browser looks at http response header for document mode only if the meta tag doesn't specify anything about it. Meta tag and X-UA-Compatible in the http response header do exactly the same thing.

Comment: This has always worked for me, I've never had a problem with setting it at the IIS level.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The Browser Mode is intended to be used by developers to see what their browser would look like with new features disabled (for instance, if I put my IE10 into the IE8 Browser Mode, it will no longer support `border-radius`, or anything else that was added).

Since it's a developer tool, there is no need for it on the regular user's side.

The Document Mode, on the other hand, involves how the document is rendered, not how it is supported. I can have my document in IE8 mode and still have rounded corners because the browser mode supports it.

That being said, you should ALWAYS use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

If I see a site with a `X-UA-Compatible` header that contains anything else, I assume that the developer is a lazy bastard.